# How to use $navigateTo in natviescript-vue vuex store actions?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

`this.$navigateTo` works perfectly fine within the methods of my components, but inside a mutation neither of `Vue.$navigateTo` and `this.$navigateTo` work. My navigation depends on the result I get from an api call, if there is no way to perform a navigation from within store actions, how can I get some return value from an store action so I can perform my navigation within my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a value from a store action. Since actions are async, you will need to handle the resulting promise, doing something like

```
store.dispatch('actionA').then((target) => {
  // navigate to target
})
```

The concept is explained here:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions

Answer (score 0):

Here is How I solved it:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(store.state.is_logged_in ? App : Login)]),
  created() {
    this.$store.commit('setNav', t => this.$navigateTo(t));
    if (this.$store.state.is_logged_in) {
      this.$store.dispatch('init');
    }
  },
}).$start();
```

Now in my actions I do:

```
logout({commit, state}) {
  console.log('logged out');
  commit('log_out');
  state.nav(Login);
},
```